# Running a batch file remotely, displaying results to user & allowing user to provide input

Tags: c#

I've made a page that allows users to view a list of batch files on a server, and run them.

The problem is when a batch file requires input such as "Press any key to continue" or "Press Y if you're sure you want to continue". Currently my code is providing input to preset situations:

```
if (outputLine.Contains("Y or N"))
    inputLine = "Y";
if (outputLine.Contains("pause"))
    inputLine = "X";
```

But I now want to give the user the ability to provide input instead of my code.

I've spent most of today researching how to do this and have come up with nothing.

Here's my code:

```
private void RunScript(int scriptId)
{
    ScriptData data = new ScriptData();
    Script script = data.GetScript(scriptId);

    ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo()
    {
        FileName = script.Path,
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        RedirectStandardInput = true,
        UseShellExecute = false,
        CreateNoWindow = false
    };

    Process proc = new Process();
    proc.StartInfo = psi;

    proc.Start();

    StreamReader reader = proc.StandardOutput;
    StreamWriter writer = proc.StandardInput;

    string outputLine;
    string inputLine = string.Empty;
    string display = string.Empty;

    while (!reader.EndOfStream)
    {
        outputLine = reader.ReadLine();
        display += outputLine + "\r\n";

        if (inputLine != string.Empty)
            display += inputLine + "\r\n";

        inputLine = string.Empty;
        if (outputLine.Contains("Y or N"))
            inputLine = "Y";
        if (outputLine.Contains("pause"))
            inputLine = "X";

        if (inputLine != string.Empty)
            writer.WriteLine(inputLine);
    }

    display = Server.HtmlEncode(display);
    display = display.Replace("\r\n", "<br />");
    litOutput.Text = display;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved the problem, what I've got now when I run a script is very close to a command prompt window.

Here's a very basic summary of how it works:

I start a new process that runs a batch file. At the same time I start a newthread that continuously loops asking the process for more output, and storing that output in a queue. My .NET timer continuously checks the queue for text, and outputs it into my ajax panel. I use a text box and ajax to input text into the process input and into my ajax panel. Also needed a lot of javascript and I had to use session variables to make it run smoothly.

```
// ====== ====== ====== ====== ====== ====== ====== ====== ====== ====== ======//

<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeBehind="Scripts.aspx.cs" Inherits="MITool.Scripts" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        var script = '';

        function ShowScriptModal() {
            $('#overlay').css({ width: $(document).width(), height: $(document).height(), 'display': 'block' }).animate({ opacity: 0.85 }, 0, function () { $('#scriptModal').show(); });
        }

        function ScriptInputKeypress(e) {
            if (e.keyCode == 13) {
                ScriptInput();
            }
        }

        function ScriptInput() {
            var txtInput = document.getElementById("txtInput");
            var input = txtInput.value;
            var hiddenInput = document.getElementById("hiddenInput");

            if (input == '')
                return;

            hiddenInput.value = input;

            txtInput.value = '';
        }

        function CheckForNewOutput() {
            var outputUpdatePanel = document.getElementById("OutputUpdatePanel");
            var pageScript = outputUpdatePanel.innerHTML;
            if (script != pageScript) {
                script = pageScript;
                ScrollToBottom();
            }
            setTimeout("CheckForNewOutput()", 100);
        }

        function ScrollToBottom() {
            $('#OutputPanel').scrollTop($('#OutputUpdatePanel').height());
        }
    </script>
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true" EnablePartialRendering="true" LoadScriptsBeforeUI="true" />
    <div id="scriptModal">
        <div id="ScriptInputOutput">
            <asp:Panel ID="OutputPanel" runat="server" Width="700" Height="250" ScrollBars="Vertical"
                Style="margin: 10px auto; border: 1px solid #CCC; padding: 5px;" ClientIDMode="Static">
                <controls:ScriptOutput ID="ScriptOutputControl" runat="server" />
            </asp:Panel>
            <asp:Panel ID="InputPanel" runat="server" DefaultButton="btnScriptInput" >
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtInput" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" onkeypress="ScriptInputKeypress(event)" />
                <asp:HiddenField ID="hiddenInput" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" />
                <asp:Button ID="btnScriptInput" runat="server" Text="Script Input" ClientIDMode="Static" OnClick="btnScriptInput_Click" style="display:none" />           
                <asp:Button ID="btnExit" runat="server" CssClass="floatRight" Text="Exit" OnClick="btnExit_Click" />
            </asp:Panel>
        </div>
    </div>
    <asp:Literal ID="litScript" runat="server" />
    <ul id="breadcrumb">
        <li><a href="/dashboard.aspx">Main page</a> &gt;</li>
        <li class="current">Scripts</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="content">
        <h2>
            <asp:Label ID="lblHeader" runat="server" Text="Scripts" /></h2>
        <div class="clear">
        </div>
        <div class="table-content">
            <asp:Label ID="lblMessage" runat="server" CssClass="redMessage" />
            <asp:Repeater ID="rptScripts" runat="server" OnItemCommand="rptScripts_ItemCommand">
                <HeaderTemplate>
                    <table class="table" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                        <tr>
                            <th>
                                ID
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                Name
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                Location
                            </th>
                            <th>
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                </HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <%# Eval("ScriptId") %>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <%# Eval("Name") %>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <%# Eval("Path") %>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="btnRunScript" runat="server" Text="Run" CommandName="Run" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ScriptId") %>' />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    </table>
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
            <div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        CheckForNewOutput();
    </script>
</asp:Content>

// ====== ====== ====== ====== ====== ====== ====== ====== ====== ====== ======//

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using MITool.Data.ScriptManager;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Threading;

namespace MITool
{
    public partial class Scripts : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        ConcurrentQueue<char> ScriptOutputQueue
        {
            get
            {
                return (ConcurrentQueue<char>)Session["ScriptOutputQueue"];
            }
            set
            {
                Session["ScriptOutputQueue"] = value;
            }
        }
        Process CurrentProcess
        {
            get
            {
                return (Process)Session["CurrentProcess"];
            }
            set
            {
                Session["CurrentProcess"] = value;
            }
        }
        bool ScriptRunning
        {
            get
            {
                if (CurrentProcess == null)
                    return false;
                if (!CurrentProcess.HasExited || !CurrentProcess.StandardOutput.EndOfStream)
                    return true;
                return false;
            }
        }
        bool OutputProcessing
        {
            get
            {
                if (ScriptOutputQueue != null && ScriptOutputQueue.Count != 0)
                    return true;
                return false;
            }
        }

        Thread OutputThread;

        void Reset()
        {
            ScriptOutputControl.SetTimerEnabled(false);
            ScriptOutputControl.ClearOutputText();
            if (CurrentProcess != null && !CurrentProcess.HasExited)
                CurrentProcess.Kill();
            if (OutputThread != null && OutputThread.IsAlive)
                OutputThread.Abort();
            ScriptOutputQueue = new ConcurrentQueue<char>();

            litScript.Text = string.Empty;
            txtInput.Text = string.Empty;
        }

        void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (IsPostBack) return;

            Reset();

            FormsIdentity id = (FormsIdentity)HttpContext.Current.User.Identity;
            string role = id.Ticket.UserData;

            ScriptData data = new ScriptData();
            List<Script> scripts = data.GetScriptsByRole(role);
            rptScripts.DataSource = scripts;
            rptScripts.DataBind();
        }

        protected void rptScripts_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            switch (e.CommandName)
            {
                case "Run": StartScript(Int32.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString()));
                    break;
            }
        }

        void StartScript(int id)
        {
            if (ScriptRunning || OutputProcessing)
                return;

            Reset();

            ScriptData data = new ScriptData();
            History history = new History()
            {
                UserName = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name,
                BatchFileId = id,
                DateRun = DateTime.Now
            };
            data.CreateHistory(history);            

            Script script = data.GetScript(id);

            ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo()
            {
                FileName = script.Path,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                RedirectStandardInput = true,
                UseShellExecute = false,
                CreateNoWindow = true
            };

            CurrentProcess = new Process();
            CurrentProcess.StartInfo = psi;

            OutputThread = new Thread(Output);

            CurrentProcess.Start();
            OutputThread.Start();

            ScriptOutputControl.SetTimerEnabled(true);

            litScript.Text = "<script type=\"text/javascript\" language=\"javascript\">ShowScriptModal();</script>";

            SetFocus("txtInput");
        }

        void Output()
        {
            while (ScriptRunning)
            {
                var x = CurrentProcess.StandardOutput.Read();
                if (x != -1)
                    ScriptOutputQueue.Enqueue((char)x);
            }
        }

        public void btnScriptInput_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string input = hiddenInput.Value.ToString();

            ScriptOutputControl.Input(input);

            foreach (char x in input.ToArray())
            {
                if (CurrentProcess != null && !CurrentProcess.HasExited)
                {
                    CurrentProcess.StandardInput.Write(x);
                }
                Thread.Sleep(1);
            }
        }

        protected void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Reset();
        }
    }
}

// ====== ====== ====== ====== ====== ====== ====== ====== ====== ====== ======//

<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ScriptOutput.ascx.cs"
    Inherits="MITool.Controls.ScriptOutput" %>
<asp:Label ID="lblStats" runat="server" Style="color: Red" />
<br />
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="OutputUpdatePanel" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static">
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="UpdateTimer" EventName="Tick" />
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnScriptInput" EventName="Click" />
    </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Literal ID="litOutput" runat="server" />
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
<asp:Timer ID="UpdateTimer" Interval="100" runat="server" OnTick="UpdateTimer_Tick" Enabled="false" />

// ====== ====== ====== ====== ====== ====== ====== ====== ====== ====== ======//

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace MITool.Controls
{
    public partial class ScriptOutput : System.Web.UI.UserControl
    {
        string Output
        {
            get
            {
                if (Session["Output"] != null)
                    return Session["Output"].ToString();
                return string.Empty;
            }
            set
            {
                Session["Output"] = value;
            }
        }

        ConcurrentQueue<char> ScriptOutputQueue
        {
            get
            {
                return (ConcurrentQueue<char>)Session["ScriptOutputQueue"];
            }
            set
            {
                Session["ScriptOutputQueue"] = value;
            }
        }
        Process CurrentProcess
        {
            get
            {
                return (Process)Session["CurrentProcess"];
            }
            set
            {
                Session["CurrentProcess"] = value;
            }
        }
        bool ScriptRunning
        {
            get
            {
                if (CurrentProcess == null)
                    return false;
                if (!CurrentProcess.HasExited || CurrentProcess.StandardOutput.Peek() != -1)
                    return true;
                return false;
            }
        }
        bool OutputProcessing
        {
            get
            {
                if (ScriptOutputQueue != null && ScriptOutputQueue.Count != 0)
                    return true;
                return false;
            }
        }

        public void SetTimerEnabled(bool enabled)
        {
            UpdateTimer.Enabled = enabled;
        }
        public void ClearOutputText()
        {
            Output = string.Empty;
            litOutput.Text = Output;
        }

        protected void UpdateTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ProcessOutput();

            if (!ScriptRunning && !OutputProcessing)
            {
                UpdateTimer.Enabled = false;

                Output += "<br />// SCRIPT END //<br />";
                litOutput.Text = Output;
            }
        }

        public void Input(string s) 
        {
            Output += "<br />// " + s + "<br />";
        }

        void ProcessOutput()
        {
            string s = string.Empty;

            while (ScriptOutputQueue != null && ScriptOutputQueue.Any())
            {
                char x;
                if (ScriptOutputQueue.TryDequeue(out x))
                {
                    s += x;
                }
            }

            if (s != string.Empty)
            {
                s = Server.HtmlEncode(s);
                s = s.Replace("\r\n", "<br />");

                Output += s;
            }

            litOutput.Text = Output;
        }
    }
}

// ====== ====== ====== ====== ====== ====== ====== ====== ====== ====== ======/
```